# How to get the value of interseption of a Matrix in a new Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a dataframe with combinations between occurencers in two columns:

```
    A   B
0   a   z
1   a   y
2   b   z
3   c   z
4   c   y
5   c   x
```

And a matrix in a different dataframe with the values got from the combination of all possible values of A and B:

```
    x   y   z
a   0.5 0.3 0.2
b   0.3 0.9 0.1
c   0.6 0.8 0.7
```

I would like to get their interseption in a new column of the main dataframe, searching the pair of values in this table and getting the correspondent interseption from the other dataframe. Example:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   z   0.2
1   a   y   0.3
2   b   z   0.1
3   c   z   0.7
4   c   y   0.8
5   c   x   0.6
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The solution you proposed does not solve this one. This comes from a different dataframe

Comment: Yes, they are not in my real problem. I will update it as it seems it is, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df1.join(df2.stack().rename('C'), on=['A','B'])
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  a  z  0.2
1  a  y  0.3
2  a  x  0.5
3  b  z  0.1
4  b  y  0.9
5  b  x  0.3
6  c  z  0.7
7  c  y  0.8
8  c  x  0.6
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't give you +1 because I don't have the reputation for it, but I would give you +10 :D